# Doing git-push without origin master

Tags: git, git-push

Is there a way on GIT to just do a "git push" and it automatically send to "origin master" without specify that?
Just curious...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your master branch should be automatically setup so this works. If you are on some other branch, then you can use the git branch command with the --set-upstream option

```
git branch --set-upstream someBranch origin/master
```

It might be also the case that you don't have a remote set, in the case when you have a bare and clean repository setup waiting for you to push to it for the first time, e.g. when you are setting up a repo on github. Assuming you have setup your remote you can push to the server with the -u option that will take care of the branch --set-upstream for you:

```
git push -u origin master
```

which is the same as:

```
git push origin master
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

Comment: how to automatically setup the master branch ?

Comment: When you `git clone` it will be set up automatically.  When you create branches, there are special --track arguments which will set up the relationship for new local copies of remote branches.

Comment: I revised my answer a little bit.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Answer (score 2):

`git push` already does `git push origin master` when you are in master.

> ```
> git push
> ```
>
> Works like `git push <remote>`, where `<remote>` is the current branch’s
>   remote (or origin, if no remote is configured for the current branch).

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour is defined by the push.default configuration setting.

If you do a search for push.default on http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config you'll find an explanation for its various options.