# How to configure default push on Heroku?

Tags: facebook, git, heroku

When I create a Heroku app on Facebook, this is all I have to do to push my changes to the server.

```
git push
```

But if I create an app with `heroku create` then that doesn't work. I have to type something like

```
git push heroku master
```

every time I want to push to the server.

How can I get it so I can just type `git push`?

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074009/doing-git-push-without-origin-master)

Comment: Is there a file in the directory that git reads to find out these default values?

Answer (score 2):

on your the repo's Git config file (`.git/config`):

```
[branch "master"]
   remote = heroku
   merge = refs/heads/master
```